# How can I improve my question to attract meaningful answers?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Ask Ubuntu post:

- [Why don't POSIX regular expression character classes work in mawk?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/751734)

How can I improve my question to attract meaningful answers? This is a very frustrating software bug which has been troubling us for almost a decade. I have tried to include specifics including command examples showing input and output, version information, and quotes from official sources. I even edited the post with a link to a bug report. So far I only got one non-answer comment which, aside from being unhelpful, has served only to discourage me from using this site.

Comment: I don't think there is anything you can do to that question to get the bug fixed. We are not the developers or maintainers of the package, so it is unlikely anyone can help.Contact the devs. As you say this is a known bug the question is off topic anyway, bugs should be reported on launchpad. Also you did get a comment from muru, why not respond to him? he mentioned better alternatives, ask for one.

Comment: @markkirby Considering OP did use one of the better alternatives in the question, they don't need to ask. :D

Comment: I don't understand. Is my question not welcome here?

Comment: @markkirby Oh, I tried to respond to muru, but the site won't let me.

Comment: @LowPowah We don't fix bugs in peoples code, we just offer support for Ubuntu. If you have as bug report it to the devs so they can do something about it.

Answer (score 4):

As no one has given you an answer: Ask Ubuntu is all about providing support for [Ubuntu and its official derivatives](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuFlavors) by an army of volunteers (no we don't get paid for doing this) so everyone answers the questions they like and know something about.

There are a few things [we do](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) and [don't do](https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask), but I suspect you never received an answer to your [original question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/751734/why-dont-posix-regular-expression-character-classes-work-in-mawk) because *no one uses `mawk` any more because there are [better alternatives](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=alternative+mawk)*.

And why Canonical (the company behind Ubuntu) still ships `mawk`?  We can only guess, and that is off-opic here...  **;-)**

So what can you do if `mawk` is that important to you?

Well, fix the bug yourself, hire a developer to do it for you and post the fix upstream, contact the developer, ... But definitely, [go here](http://invisible-island.net/mawk/mawk.html)!

## ;-)

Comment: The bug's fixed - the maintainer is [an active user](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/105132/thomas-dickey) on [unix.se] and that bug's been fixed long ago. Nobody updated the Ubuntu package.

Comment: [Old article](https://brenocon.com/blog/2009/09/dont-mawk-awk-the-fastest-and-most-elegant-big-data-munging-language/), but perhaps it still applies to some extent: the reason why Ubuntu still ships with MAWK might be that MAWK has been proven almost 8 times faster than GAWK at certain tasks.

Comment: @kos: yeah, read that one too...